# How to create a Google Pie Chart with dynamic data?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

I'm struggling to get the below google pie chart to reflect dynamic data found within a html table on the same page.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Answer', 'Percentage'],
      ['Yes',     10], //This static data needs to reflect dynamic data from html table
      ['No',      3], //This static data needs to reflect dynamic data from html table
      ['Maybe',  7], //This static data needs to reflect dynamic data from html table
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML Table:

```
<table border="1" id="results">
    <td>Result</td>
    <td> <?php echo $q['answer']; ?> </td>
</table>
```

The html table displays its data with this line:

```
<td><?php echo $q['answer']; ?></td>
```

The 'answer' can be yes, no or maybe which is defined through analysis elsewhere seen here:

```
function findAnswer($question) {
    $results=array();
    foreach($question['answer'] as $q) {
            $answer=$API->Analysis($answer['text']);
            if($answer!=false) {
                $results[]=array(
                    'answer'=>$answer,
                    );
            }
        }     
    }
```

I need the pie chart to reflect the answers yes, no or maybe to summarize the html table.

How can I get the pi chart to reflect something like this (below) where answers can change every time the the query is resubmitted?:

```
$q['answer']=='yes'
$q['answer']=='no'
$q['answer']=='maybe'
```

Thanks in advance, been trying different methods for absolutely ages!

Comment: for clarification, will you share a sample of the HTML table?

Comment: Sure thing! I've edited the code in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: drawChart
});

function drawChart() {
  // init google table
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        { label: 'Answer', type: 'string' },
        { label: 'Result', type: 'number' }
      ]
  });

  // get html table rows
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(results.rows, function(row) {
    // exclude column heading
    if (row.rowIndex > 0) {
      dataTable.addRow([
        { v: (row.cells[0].textContent || row.cells[0].innerHTML).trim() },
        { v: 1 }
      ]);
    }
  });

  var dataSummary = google.visualization.data.group(
    dataTable,
    [0],
    [{'column': 1, 'aggregation': google.visualization.data.sum, 'type': 'number'}]
  );

  var options = {
    title: 'My Daily Activities'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(dataSummary, options);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<table id="results">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Answer</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Maybe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: wasn't sure if the HTML table displays the summary results or detail answers that need to be counted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although the pie chart needs to be dynamic, the data provided (10,3,7) is just there to show it needs replacing to reflect the HTML table. The 'answer' in the html table can be shown as 'yes' 'no' or 'maybe'. So I have a table full of those three answers. I just need the pie chart to know how many of each answer there is and reflect that on the chart. Thanks!

Comment: Genius! One small problem, the pie chart is including the table heading in its statistics, any idea how to remove that from the pie chart results?

Comment: that is why, in the original answer, I set `id="results"` on the `<tbody>` instead of `<table>` -- check edit -- if it helps, will you please accept my answer?

Comment: If I place the id at table level it includes the heading but calculates the rest of the data fine, if I place it at tbody level it ignores the heading but seems to only find 1 result (the first answer in the table) and therefore the pie chart is always 100% on 1 answer!

Comment: place it at table level and skip first row, from answer --> `if (row.rowIndex > 0) {` -- or update question with latest attempt..

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic pie chart using google chart api

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  drawLeadChart("source", resp.source, 'count');
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  drawLeadChart("priority", resp.priority, 'count');
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  drawLeadChart("location", resp.location, 'count');
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  drawLeadChart("budget", resp.budget, 'count');
});

function drawLeadChart(charClass, apiLeadData, sourceType) {

  // Create the data table for Sarah's pizza.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  var obj = [];
  $.each(apiLeadData, function(i, ele) {
    let innerArr = new Array();
    innerArr.push(ele.last_name);
    if (sourceType == 'roi') {
      innerArr.push(ele.sum / ele.count);
    } else {
      innerArr.push(ele[sourceType]);
    }
    obj.push(innerArr);
  });
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows(obj);
  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'left',
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 14
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    chartArea: {
      left: 15,
      right: 10,
      top: 0,
      bottom: 20,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };
  // Instantiate and draw the chart for Sarah's pizza.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(charClass));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

output
[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRlyv.png)